# DWA-171 D-Link WiFi dongle

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb

I have a Dell Inspiron 3455 24 inch. It is one of those units where the computer is in the monitor. I have had this unit as a wall mounted slide show display for about 7 years.  It has been running windows but would not update to Windows 11 so I have been trying to install Ubuntu.
Several years ago, wifi quit working in the unit, not sure why.  The problem went away when I added a D-Link wifi dongle DWA-171 as long as I used windows.
I have a temporary ethernet connection that connects the unit to my wifi router and gets internet to the Dell but I need to get it running on wifi to get rid of the cable across my dining room.
I took the D-Link out and tried to run ubuntu thinking it might fire up the retired on motherboard wifi, but no luck with that.
When I start the unit in Ubuntu with the dongle inserted, it does not recognize the device and says there is no wifi.
Oddly, when I start the unit from a Tails usb flash drive, the net set up screen lists all of the wifi it can hear, more than a dozen of them, but there is still no connectivity.  Tails without the dongle inserted shows no wifi stations nearby.
Right now, running in ubuntu with the dongle inserted, I get this:

```
ken-walker@ken-walker-Inspiron-24-3455:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:28bc Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2149:5cfd Advanced Silicon S.A. CoolTouchR System           
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:8505 Dell Computer Corp. Dell Universal Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Getting the D-Link dongle working in Ubuntu would be great if it is not too too complicated to do.  Buying a different dongle that is more plug n play in Ubuntu would also be just fine if I knew what to get.

Thanks for any offered help

Cheers, Ken Walker

Comment: Is it inserted directly or via a hub?

Comment: Inserted directly into a USB port on the back of the computer

Comment: Sorry, we see no USB wireless in your `lsusb` result. Please try another USB port. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, it turns out I did not have the dongle inserted.  Here is the result with it in:  

ken-walker@ken-walker-Inspiron-24-3455:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:28bc Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2149:5cfd Advanced Silicon S.A. CoolTouchR System           
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2001:331d D-Link Corp. DWA-171

Answer (score 0):

> Device 006: ID 2001:331d D-Link Corp. DWA-171

With a working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential git bc dkms
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu-20210916.git
cd 8821cu-20210916
sudo ./install-driver.sh
sudo modprobe 8821cu
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Yes indeed, all set.  Thank you very much.

Comment: If my answer has been useful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour Glad it's working!